# Logistic regression using python

Tags: python, statistics, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I want to implement Logisitic regression from scratch in python. Following are the functions in it:

1. sigmoid
2. cost
3. fminunc
4. Evaluating Logistic regression

I would like to know, what would be a great start to this to start from scratch in python. Any guidance on how and what would be good. I know the theory of those functions but looking for a better pythonic answer.

I used octave and I got it all right but dont know how to start in python as OCtave already has those packages setup to do the work.

Comment: If you dont show us your code and where it goes wrong, we cant help you. We wont code instead of you, if you dont show us what you did and how it goes wrong. Show your octave code, and how you tried implementing the same thing in python, and what lines you cant seem to write in python

Comment: @usethedeathstar Please read question properly. I want to know packages in python bec there is a pythonic way of implementing it. I am nt asking u to code but asking help so I can use good python packages like octave to code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try to translate your octave code to python and see what's going on. You can also use the python package to do this for you. Check out [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) on logistic regression. There is also an easy example in this [blog](http://blog.yhathq.com/posts/logistic-regression-and-python.html).

Comment: Does scikit-learn already have logistic regression implemented? or the math packages like Octave. Bec I am looking to implement in python from scratch and if scikit learn already has it implemented then its no point

Comment: scikit-learn has logistic regression function included. You can write yourself if you would like to as well, and compare your result with scikit

Answer (score 1):

In order to implement Logistic Regression, You may consider the following 2 approaches:

1. Consider How Linear Regression Works. Apply Sigmoid Function to the Hypothesis of Linear Regression and run gradient Descent until convergence. OR Apply the Exponential based Softmax function to rule out lower possibility of occurrence.

   ```
   def logistic_regression(x, y,alpha=0.05,lamda=0):
       '''
       Logistic regression for datasets
       '''
       m,n=np.shape(x)
       theta=np.ones(n)
       xTrans = x.transpose()
       oldcost=0.0
       value=True
       while(value):
           hypothesis = np.dot(x, theta)
           logistic=hypothesis/(np.exp(-hypothesis)+1)
           reg = (lamda/2*m)*np.sum(np.power(theta,2))
           loss = logistic - y
           cost = np.sum(loss ** 2)
           #print(cost)
           # avg cost per example (the 2 in 2*m doesn't really matter here.
           # But to be consistent with the gradient, I include it)
           # avg gradient per example
           gradient = np.dot(xTrans, loss)/m
           # update
           if(reg):
               cost=cost+reg
               theta = (theta - (alpha) * (gradient+reg))
           else:
               theta=theta -(alpha/m) * gradient
           if(oldcost==cost):
               value=False
           else:
               oldcost=cost
       print(accuracy(theta,m,y,x))
       return theta,accuracy(theta,m,y,x)
   ```

Comment: i think you already have included (1/m) while calculating gradient
so no need to include it while re calculating theta

Comment: And i think the logistic variable should be = 1/(np.exp(-hypothesis)+1) and not hypothesis/(np.exp(-hypothesis)+1)